# Unit testing Bash scripts

Tags: bash, testing, tdd, automated-tests, extreme-programming

We have a system that has some Bash scripts running besides Java code. Since we are trying to *test everything that could possibly break*, and those Bash scripts may break, we want to test them.

The problem is it is hard to test Bash scripts.

Is there a way or a best practice to test Bash scripts? Or should we quit using Bash scripts and look for alternative solutions that are testable?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315624/bash-and-test-driven-development

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing for shell scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971945/unit-testing-for-shell-scripts)

Comment: Overview of the existing tools: https://medium.com/wemake-services/testing-bash-applications-85512e7fe2de

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I got the following answer from a discussion group:

> it's possible to import (include,
> whatever) a procedure (function,
> whatever it's named) from an external
> file. That's the key to writing a
> testing script: you break up your
> script into independent procedures
> that can then be imported into both
> your running script and your testing
> script, and then you have your running
> script be as simple as possible.

This method is like [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) for scripts and sounds reasonable. Avoiding Bash scripts and using more testable and less obscure language is preferable.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should vote up or down, on one hand dividing to smaller parts is good, but on second hand I need a framework not a set of custom scripts

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with bash (I wrote many, many scripts), it is a  hard language to master.  My rule of thumb is if a script is large enough to need tests, you should probably move on to a scripting language that is easily tested.

Comment: But sometimes you need to have something that can be sourced in a users' shell. It's not clear to me how you'd do that without resorting to a shell script

Comment: @Itkovian - you could, for example, use npm to export an executable to the path, so no sourcing is necessary (your npm package will have to be installed globally)

Comment: I'm going to follow the advice about not using bash. :)

Answer (score 60):

There is actually a [shunit2](http://github.com/kward/shunit2), an xUnit based unit test framework for Bourne based shell scripts. I haven't used it myself, but it might be worth checking out.

Similar questions have been asked before:

- [Unit Testing for Shell Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971945/unit-testing-for-shell-scripts)
- [Test Anything Protocol in Shell Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745266/test-anything-protocol-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: I can assert (pun intended) that shunit2 (version 2.1.6) is a bit broken to date. The assertNull and assertNotNull don't work, even if you feed them direct values. assertEquals works fine, but I think I'm just going to have to roll my own for now.

Comment: @labyrinth, are you sure the problem was not a case of this: https://github.com/kward/shunit2/issues/53 "How to use assertNull correctly?"?

Comment: @Victor It's definitely possible I wasn't careful enough with my double-quotes. I'm soon moving back into a role where shunit2 or some bash unit-testing system will be very useful. I'll give it a try again.

Comment: I am a user and sometimes contributor to shunit2, and I can confirm that the project is alive and well in 2019.

Answer (score 41):

[TAP](http://testanything.org/)-compliant Bash testing: **[Bash Automated Testing System](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core)**

> TAP, the Test Anything Protocol, is a simple text-based interface between testing modules in a test harness. TAP started life as part of the test harness for Perl but now has implementations in C, C++, Python, PHP, Perl, Java, JavaScript, and others.

[bats-core](/questions/tagged/bats-core)

Comment: It's worth disclosing what TAP is and why should one care, otherwise it's just meaningless copy-paste

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I linked it to the TAP site now.

Comment: Since no one else was saying the unsayable: TAP = 
Test Anything Protocol

Answer (score 16):

I created [shellspec](https://github.com/shellspec/shellspec), because I wanted a easy-to-use and useful tool.

It written by a pure POSIX shell script. It has been tested with many shells more than shunit2. It has more powerful features than bats/bats-core.

For example, it supports nested block, easy to mock/stub, easy to skip/pending, parameterized tests, assertion line number, execute by line number, parallel execution, random execution, [TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol)/[JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) formatter, coverage and [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) integration, profiler, etc.

See the demo on the project page.

- https://github.com/shellspec/shellspec
- https://shellspec.info/

Answer (score 13):

Nikita Sobolev wrote an excellent blog post comparing a few different Bash test frameworks, [Testing Bash applications](https://medium.com/wemake-services/testing-bash-applications-85512e7fe2de). These are the frameworks listed in that post:

- [assert.sh](https://github.com/lehmannro/assert.sh)
- [shunit2](https://github.com/kward/shunit2)
- [roundup](https://github.com/bmizerany/roundup)
- [Bats](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats) -> [Bats-core](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core)

For the impatient: Nikita's conclusion was to use [Bats](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats), but it appears that Nikita missed the [Bats-core](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) project which appear to me to be the one to use going forward as the original Bats project has not been actively maintained since 2013.

Answer (score 8):

I can't believe no one talked about [OSHT](https://github.com/coryb/osht)! It's compatible with *both* [TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol) and [JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit), it's pure shell (that is, no other languages involved), it works standalone too, and it's simple and direct.

Testing looks like this (snippets taken from the project page):

```
#!/bin/bash
. osht.sh

# Optionally, indicate number of tests to safeguard against abnormal exits
PLAN 13

# Comparing stuff
IS $(whoami) != root
var="foobar"
IS "$var" =~ foo
ISNT "$var" == foo

# test(1)-based tests
OK -f /etc/passwd
NOK -w /etc/passwd

# Running stuff
# Check exit code
RUNS true
NRUNS false

# Check stdio/stdout/stderr
RUNS echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz'
GREP bar
OGREP bar
NEGREP . # verify empty

# diff output
DIFF <<EOF
foo
bar
baz
EOF

# TODO and SKIP
TODO RUNS false
SKIP test $(uname -s) == Darwin
```

A simple run:

```
$ bash test.sh
1..13
ok 1 - IS $(whoami) != root
ok 2 - IS "$var" =~ foo
ok 3 - ISNT "$var" == foo
ok 4 - OK -f /etc/passwd
ok 5 - NOK -w /etc/passwd
ok 6 - RUNS true
ok 7 - NRUNS false
ok 8 - RUNS echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz'
ok 9 - GREP bar
ok 10 - OGREP bar
ok 11 - NEGREP . # verify empty
ok 12 - DIFF <<EOF
not ok 13 - TODO RUNS false # TODO Test Know to fail
```

The last test shows as "not ok", but the exit code is 0 because it's a `TODO`. One can set verbose as well:

```
$ OSHT_VERBOSE=1 bash test.sh # Or -v
1..13
# dcsobral \!= root
ok 1 - IS $(whoami) != root
# foobar =\~ foo
ok 2 - IS "$var" =~ foo
# \! foobar == foo
ok 3 - ISNT "$var" == foo
# test -f /etc/passwd
ok 4 - OK -f /etc/passwd
# test \! -w /etc/passwd
ok 5 - NOK -w /etc/passwd
# RUNNING: true
# STATUS: 0
# STDIO <<EOM
# EOM
ok 6 - RUNS true
# RUNNING: false
# STATUS: 1
# STDIO <<EOM
# EOM
ok 7 - NRUNS false
# RUNNING: echo -e foo\\nbar\\nbaz
# STATUS: 0
# STDIO <<EOM
# foo
# bar
# baz
# EOM
ok 8 - RUNS echo -e 'foo\nbar\nbaz'
# grep -q bar
ok 9 - GREP bar
# grep -q bar
ok 10 - OGREP bar
# \! grep -q .
ok 11 - NEGREP . # verify empty
ok 12 - DIFF <<EOF
# RUNNING: false
# STATUS: 1
# STDIO <<EOM
# EOM
not ok 13 - TODO RUNS false # TODO Test Know to fail
```

Rename it to use a `.t` extension and put it in a `t` subdirectory, and you can use `prove(1)` (part of Perl) to run it:

```
$ prove
t/test.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=13,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.01 sys +  0.11 cusr  0.16 csys =  0.31 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Set `OSHT_JUNIT` or pass `-j` to produce JUnit output. JUnit can also be combined with `prove(1)`.

I have used this library both testing functions by sourcing their files and then running assertions with `IS`/`OK` and their negatives, and scripts by using `RUN`/`NRUN`. For me, this framework provides the most gain for the least overhead.

Answer (score 7):

[Epoxy](https://github.com/spbnick/epoxy) is a Bash test framework I designed mainly for testing other software, but I use it to test Bash modules as well, including [itself](https://github.com/spbnick/epoxy/tree/master/tests) and [Carton](https://github.com/spbnick/carton/tree/master/tests).

The main advantages are relatively low coding overhead, unlimited assertion nesting and flexible selection of assertions to verify.

I made [a presentation](http://slid.es/spbnick/epoxy) comparing it to [BeakerLib](https://fedorahosted.org/beakerlib/) - a framework used by some at Red Hat.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you say that it's "hard" to test Bash scripts?

What's wrong with test wrappers like the following?

```
 #!/bin/bash
 set -e
 errors=0
 results=$($script_under_test $args<<ENDTSTDATA
 # inputs
 # go
 # here
 #
 ENDTSTDATA
 )
 [ "$?" -ne 0 ] || {
     echo "Test returned error code $?" 2>&1
     let errors+=1
     }

 echo "$results" | grep -q $expected1 || {
      echo "Test Failed.  Expected $expected1"
      let errors+=1
 }
 # And so on, et cetera, ad infinitum, ad nauseum
 [ "$errors" -gt 0 ] && {
      echo "There were $errors errors found"
      exit 1
 }
```

Comment: First, bash scripts are not very readable. Second, expectations are complicated like checking if a lock file is created with the PID of the bash script that created it.

Comment: More importantly, it's hard to test shell scripts because they generally have a large number of side effects and utilize system resources such as filesystem, network, etc.  Ideally, unit tests are side-effect free and do not depend on system resources.

Answer (score 4):

Give [assert.sh](https://github.com/torokmark/assert.sh) a try:

```bash
source "./assert.sh"

local expected actual
expected="Hello"
actual="World!"
assert_eq "$expected" "$actual" "not equivalent!"
# => x Hello == World :: not equivalent!
```

Answer (score 3):

I quite like [shell2junit](https://code.google.com/p/shell2junit), a utility to generate [JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit)-like output from Bash script tests. This is useful because the report generated can then be read by continuous integration systems, such as the JUnit plug-ins for [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) and [Bamboo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian).

While shell2junit doesn't provide the comprehensive Bash scripting framework like [shunit2](https://code.google.com/p/shunit2/), it does allow you have nice reporting of the test results.

Answer (score 3):

Try [bashtest](https://github.com/pahaz/bashtest). It’s simple way to test your scripts. For example, you have `do-some-work.sh` which changes some configuration files. For example, add a new line, `PASSWORD = 'XXXXX'`, to configuration file `/etc/my.cfg`.

You write Bash commands line by line and then check output.

Install:

```
pip3 install bashtest
```

Create tests is a just writing bash commands.

File `test-do-some-work.bashtest`:

```
# Run the script
$ ./do-some-work.sh > /dev/null

# Testing that the line "PASSWORD = 'XXXXX'" is in the file /etc/my.cfg
$ grep -Fxq "PASSWORD = 'XXXXX'" /etc/my.cfg && echo "YES"
YES
```

Run tests:

```
bashtest *.bashtest
```

You can find [some examples here](https://github.com/pahaz/bashtest/blob/master/test_nginx_logs_counting_unique_ip.bashtest) and [here](https://github.com/pahaz/bashtest/blob/master/test_wc.bashtest).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can be used, or contributed to:

https://thorsteinssonh.github.io/bash_test_tools/

It is intended to write results in the TAP protocol which I imagine is good for [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and is good for those that want shell environments. I imagine some things run in shell environments, so some might argue it should be tested in their shell environment.

Answer (score 3):

I can highly recommend https://bashunit.typeddevs.com/

It is a pretty fresh and simple testing library for bash scripts.

- Free and open source license
- Easy to install
- Well documented
- Active community and engaged ownership

Answer (score 2):

I’ve tried a lot of the solutions presented here, but I found most of them too bulky and hard to use, so I built my own little testing framework: https://github.com/SnacOverflow/t-bash

It’s just one file in the repository that you can simply run directly, with a basic set of [JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) style asserts.

I’ve used it professionally in several internal projects and were able to make our Bash scripts super stable and regression resistant.

Answer (score 1):

Create a test `mytest.sh`. It calls your script with specific inputs.

Create a text file `expected/mytest.stdout`. It contains the expected output for the test.

Commit them to version control (if any).

Run the test and redirect the output to another file:

```
mytest.sh > actual/mytest.stdout
```

Then just us a text diff tool to see where the results deviate. I think you can just do

```
diff expected/mytest.stdout actual/mytest.stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at bash_unit:

https://github.com/pgrange/bash_unit

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Outthentic](https://dev.to/melezhik/command-line-application-tests-made-easy-with-outthentic-j49). It is simple, extensible by many languages ([Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl), [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), and Bash on choice) and cross platform (Linux and Windows) framework to test any command line applications.