# Testing a bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Can someone explain how to test for a bash shell script?

For example i've got a .sh file with this code in it...

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *.txt; do
    mv "$file" "`basename $file .txt`.doc"
done
```

How do I write a test for it? Like in Java you've got unit testing where you write code like assertEquals to test the code gives the desired output.

Comment: check these --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315624/bash-and-test-driven-development , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339416/testing-bash-scripts

Comment: unit tested bash scripts. Nice. :)

Comment: This is better: `mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .txt).doc"` or `mv "$file" "${file%*.txt}.doc"`

Answer (score 18):

Try this out: [assert.sh](https://github.com/torokmark/assert.sh)

```bash
source "./assert.sh"

local expected actual
expected="Hello"
actual="World!"
assert_eq "$expected" "$actual" "not equivalent!"
# => x Hello == World :: not equivalent!
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do asserts in Bash. Check out this from the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html#ASSERT

Comment: Please don't encourage the ABS as a reference -- as a rule, it's undermaintained, and makes a habit of showcasing bad-practice examples. The Wooledge wiki and the bash-hackers wiki (and of course the official manual) are *much* better resources.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Generally good advice but not very helpful in this case as you haven't pointed at an alternative and ABS does at least provide an assert script whereas neither the Wooledge wiki (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/FindPage?action=fullsearch&advancedsearch=1&and_terms=assert&or_terms=&not_terms=&mtime=&categories=&language=&mimetype=) nor the Bash Hackers Wiki (https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/start?do=search&id=assert) contain any discussion of assertions at all.

Answer (score 4):

I'd add an `echo` in front of the `mv` to verify that the right commands are being created, for starters.  (Always a good idea with commands that make possibly difficult to undo changes.)

Some possibly useful resources:

- [shUnit2](http://code.google.com/p/shunit2/) — xUnit framework for script unit testing
- [Bash IDE for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=365)
- [Bash debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Alright, thanks. But i'm trying to create a .sh file that test that whole code.

Comment: @Mr Teeth: added some links above.  That said, shell scripts are a little harder to unit test effectively because almost everything boils down to invoking external commands.  It's almost more sensible and useful to test those commands, and test the script itself by stubbing external modifications out with `echo`, as a result.