# How to test shell commands on the real file?

Tags: shell

I have to test several shell commands on the real file that I create to make sure they work. I have a windows and a mac computers. Please, provide me step by step instructions on how to do it preferably on mac.

Here is a list of problems and commands that I have to test to make sure they work properly:

*1) There is a huge tab-delimited file "fileGrand", it has 10 columns, the values in 6th column are integers. How to verify that all of these conditions were satisfied?*

```
nawk 'NF != 10 {printf("[%d] has invalid [%d] number of fields\n", FNR, NF)} $6 !~ /^[0-9]+$/ {printf("[%d] 6th field is invalid [%s]\n", FNR, $6)}' fileGrand
```

*2) The same file. Each value in column 3 is unique. How to verify that?*

```
awk -F$'\t' '$3 in a {exit 3} {a[$3]}' fileGrand
```

*3) Count the number of occurrences of the word "blue" in the file fileGrand.*

```
CountOcc () { echo $(grep -o "blue" fileGrand | wc -l) ; }
```

*4) Log the output and error message of a program into a file.*

```
unix_command >logfilename 2>&1
```

Comment: Maybe post a new question for each homework question...

Comment: I'm asking how to test these commands to make sure they work.

Comment: And how you'd test each command is different.

Comment: BTW, `echo $(foo)` is silly; just have your function call `foo`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339416/unit-testing-bash-scripts; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971945/unit-testing-for-shell-scripts; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745266/test-anything-protocol-in-shell-scripts; etc.

Comment: what unix emulator can I use to test this?